# Override default panels value when adding content

Tags: panels

I'd like to modify the default values when adding content to a panel.

Right now, when I try to add content to a panel, the default values are the shown in the following figure.

[image]

What I'd like to achieve, no matter how, is to set them as the following figure for every new content that is going to be added to a panel.

[image]